# renderPlot into renderUI - error object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show in my shiny app **one only plot**: if I select dynamically A, the shiny app must show `plot(c(1:3))`, else the shiny app must show a **grViz** class object.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("optionsplots"),
    uiOutput("plot")),
  server = function(input, output) {


    output$optionsplots <- renderUI({
      selectInput("options", "Options to plot:",choices=c("A","B"))
    }) 


    output$plot <- renderUI({


      if(input$options == 'A'){renderPlot({plot(c(1:3))})}
      else{renderGrViz({grViz("digraph boxes_and_circles {

                             # a 'graph' statement
                             graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

                             # several 'node' statements
                             node [shape = box,
                             fontname = Helvetica]
                             A; B; C; D; E; F

                             node [shape = circle,
                             fixedsize = true,
                             width = 0.9] // sets as circles
                             1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8

                             # several 'edge' statements
                             A->1 B->2 B->3 B->4 C->A
                             1->D E->A 2->4 1->5 1->F
                             E->6 4->6 5->7 6->7 3->8
      }")})}
    })
  }
),launch.browser = T)
```

*Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable*

One possible solution would be putting in ui.R `plotOutput("plot")` (for plotting plot(c(1:3))) and `grVizOutput("plot2")`(for plotting the grviz object), but I don't want it because If I don't select option "A" (or otherwise), there would be a blank space in my shiny app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work now.  You want to make input$options call inside of reactive(). Since the value is not initialized until after loading, I also set it to 'A' if null.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("optionsplots"),
    plotOutput("plot")),
  server = function(input, output) {

    getOption = reactive({ifelse(is.null(input$options),'A',input$options)})

    output$optionsplots <- renderUI({
      selectInput("options", "Options to plot:",choices=c("A","B"))
    }) 
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if(getOption() == 'A'){plot(c(1:3))}
    else{plot(c(1:6))}
    })
  }
),launch.browser = T)
```

**Edit**

Interesting edit.  The code below should work for you even though I could not find a way to make grViz work within reactivePlot().  To work around this, I created conditionalPanel items that only displayed when the item in the 'condition' argument was true (A or B was selected).  You could modify this for many conditions by just adding items to the 'condition' arguments without creating any new conditionalPanels.  Then, you would just need to add if(getOption()=='C') plot() ... within the reactivePlot() method, for example.

```
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("optionsplots"),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "['A'].indexOf(input.options)>=0",plotOutput(outputId='plot1')),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "['B'].indexOf(input.options)>=0",grVizOutput(outputId='plot2')),
    h2('next item')),
  server = function(input, output) {

    getOption = reactive({ifelse(is.null(input$options),'_',input$options)})

    output$plot1 = reactivePlot(function(){
      plot(c(1:3))
    })

    output$plot2 = renderGrViz({grViz("digraph boxes_and_circles {

              # a 'graph' statement
              graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

              # several 'node' statements
              node [shape = box,
              fontname = Helvetica]
              A; B; C; D; E; F

              node [shape = circle,
              fixedsize = true,
              width = 0.9] // sets as circles
              1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8

              # several 'edge' statements
              A->1 B->2 B->3 B->4 C->A
              1->D E->A 2->4 1->5 1->F
              E->6 4->6 5->7 6->7 3->8
      }")})

    output$optionsplots <- renderUI({
      selectInput("options", "Options to plot:",choices=c('_','A','B'))
    }) 

    }
        ),launch.browser = T)
```

Comment: yes, this works perfectly for the previous question. 
I just modified the question, and explain it better. Sorry, and thanks

Comment: It works, thanks! One question, If I would be interested to put !=A in conditional pannel, how should I modified the code `conditionalPanel(condition = "['A'].indexOf(input.options)>=0",plotOutput(outputId='plot1'))` ?

Comment: Glad it helps. `.indexOf()` is a JavaScript method. It will return -1 if `inputs.options` is not in the list `['A']`.  So you can say `conditionalPanel(condition = "['A'].indexOf(input.options)==-1",plotOutput(outputId='plot1‌​'))`. It is only useful to use this method if you have a list though (more than just A). You could just say `input.options!='A'`